# jquery dialog("open") the content is not show

Tags: jquery

using jquery dialog for a while, but now  an experience a strange behavior.

Calling:

```
$('#dialog-form').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: '700px',
    modal: true,
    hide: 'slide'
});

$('#dialog-form').dialog('option', 'buttons', {
'add' : {
    text: labelAdd,
    click: function() {
        doadd = true;
        if (typeof checkRow !== "undefined") { doadd = checkRow() };
        if (doadd) { exec(); }
    }}, 
'Cancelar': function() {$(this).dialog('close'); }
});
$("#dialog-form").dialog("open");

function exec() {
$('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
/* execute some remote code using ajax call*/
if (error) {
    $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
    return false
}
return true;
}
```

the dialog is not show correctly. It shows the "ui-widget-overlay", but not the dialog content.

it happens to me two of tree times that i call the function.

for what i could see the display property in the is set to none.

the resulting html code:

```
div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="display: none; z-index: 1002; outline: 0px none; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 700px; top: 0px; left: 320.5px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-dialog-form">
```

i manually set display to block using firebug, and it works ok.

Btw, if i pulse "esc" i can see the animation hiding the dialog.

Can i set from js the display for the div content? Or should i open / close the dialog differently?

Thanks for the help.

António

Comment: Can you make a fiddle at jsfiddle.com demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Very simple case of what i'm doing: 

http://jsfiddle.net/LTGMh/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't use jQuery UI, so there's no Dialog plugin -- you have to select jQuery 1.7.2 to get the jQuery UI option. I tried changing that, but the console is reporting that there's no dialog method for the object. I haven't gone further to figure out why that's happening.

Comment: Just update the fiddle, try http://jsfiddle.net/LTGMh/10/, putting everything in the html its easier, It runs now, and the problem is there... as you can see the dialog opens, you click add it closes and never open again... you press "esc" and you see the dialog close again....

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add

`$("#dialog-form").dialog("open").show()` to it..

I had a similar problem and this worked for me..